# How to design a bottom navigation bar like custom layout with floating button in middle

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-xml

I am trying to design a bottom navigation bar like layout with custom background colors and a add button in middle like so:

[image: Example Image]

The problem is, I am not able to find any documentation as to how I can give a bottom navigation view a custom layout with different background colors for each option. Secondly, my project is restricted to not use the Material Theme. So I have to manage it somehow by using Appcompat theme. I tried using a linear layout with nested relative layouts for each element. While that works for everything else, I am not able to position the add button exactly like this. Any suggestions?

Comment: i think you're on the right path with building your own layout instead of using a bottom navigation view, you should consider using constraint layout to make it easier if you're struggling with relative/linear

Comment: There's something close to what you need, It's "bottom app bar": 
https://material.io/components/app-bars-bottom#usage

As out friend has already said before, it's way easier if you use Constraint Layout.
You can create a horizontal chain for the four squares if options and centralize your button view. It's not that easy since you'll need to make sure button won't overlap middle button in mutliple screen size, but's It may be a good place to start.

Comment: yeah before moving to linear layout I was fiddling with constraint layout. the problem I encountered was making every option uniform size. as you may notice, even though the floating add button is placed in the middle, the views that wraps around it have uniform width. It's hard to manage this with margins alone since hard coded values make the layout look different in different devices.I wish I could place a guideline anchored to the floating button. things would have been easier that way.

Comment: @FilipeOliveira while that's a good suggestion, Since I can't use material component style in my project, The app bar doesn't look like an app bar at all.

Answer (score 0):

So I somewhat made it as close lookalike as possible. Here's what I did

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/actJobBottomNav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp">


                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/colorDeepBlue"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/actJobImgvHome"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
                            android:src="@drawable/home_white" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/home"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/colorBlue"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/actJobImgvContact"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
                            android:src="@drawable/contact_white" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/contact"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1.25"
                        android:background="@color/colorBlue"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1.25"
                        android:background="@color/colorDeepBlue"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/colorDeepBlue"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/actJobImgvSchedule"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
                            android:src="@drawable/appointment_white" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/schedule"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/colorDarkBlue"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/actJobImgvMore"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
                            android:src="@drawable/more_white" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/more"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_46sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_46sdp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_solid_filled_deep_blue_white_stroke"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:onClick="@{clickHandler::addClicked}"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_white" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

While it's not the best solution it works for now. Thanks for the suggestions.